# Homotopy equivalent space to $T^2/S^1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

> Let $T^2$ be the two-dimensional torus $S^1\times S^1$ and $C$ one of its longitudinal circles. I am trying to prove that the quotient space $T^2/C$ has the same homotopy type of $S^2\vee S^1$.

If we denote $\sim$ the equivalence relation in $S^2$ generated by $(1,0,0)\sim (-1,0,0)$, it is pretty clear that $T^2/C$ must be homeomorphic to $S^2/\sim$. From here, how can I conclude that $S^2\vee S^1$ and $S^2/\sim$ has same fundamental groups?

Comment: This is precisely example 0.8 in *Hatcher*. He shows that $S^2 \vee S^1 \simeq S^2/\!\sim$, so they have isomorphic fundamental groups.